# Python Guess number game - While loop not responding

Tags: python

I am a relative newcomer and was trying to create a game where the user and the comp take turns at guessing each others games. I know I am doing something wrong in the while / if operators when the user enters a string eg. Y.

In two places:
 1. where the user decides who should go first (`if a in ["Y", "y"]`
 2. while loop in `compguess` function (`while ans = False:`) it just skips down.

```
a = input("Shall I guess first? (Y/N):")

userscore = 1
compscore = 1

def compguess():
    global compscore
    low = 0
    high = 100
    c = 50
    ans = False
    while ans = False:
        print ("Is the number", c , "?")
        d = input("Enter Y if correct / L if your number is lower or H if higher:")
        if d in ["Y" , "y"]:
            ans = True
        elif d in ["H"]:
            high = c
            c = int((c + low) / 2)
            compscore = compscore + 1
        elif d in ["L"]:
            low = c
            c = int((c + high) / 2)
            compscore = compscore + 1
        else:
            print ("invalid input")

def userguess():
    global userscore
    g = r.randint(1,100)
    h = input("Enter your guess number:")
    i = int(h)
    while g != i:
        if g > i:
            h = input("You guessed lower. Guess again:")
            i = int(h)
            userscore = userscore + 1
        else:
            h = input("You guessed higher. Guess again:")
            i = int(h)
            userscore = userscore + 1

if a in ["Y", "y"]:
    compguess()
    userguess()
else:
    userguess()
    compguess()

if userscore == compscore:
    print("Its a tie !!")
elif userscore < compscore:
    print ("Congrats ! You won !")
else:
    print ("I won !! Better luck next time")
```

Comment: `while ans=False` is a syntax error ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd change your while loop condition to:

`while not ans:`

Also, in `r.randint(1,100)`, `r` is undefined. If you want to use a function from random, you need to import it:

You could do either `import random` or `from random import randint`. If you want to keep the `r`, you can do `import random as r`.

You should also indicate when the guessing games end. Although it's implied they flow right into each other and I was confused at first.

The wording is incorrect for the computer guessing:

```
Is the number 50 ?
Enter Y if correct / L if your number is lower or H if higher:H
Is the number 25 ?
Enter Y if correct / L if your number is lower or H if higher:L
Is the number 37 ?
Enter Y if correct / L if your number is lower or H if higher:Y
I won !! Better luck next time
```

Initial guess is 50. Then, I say my number is higher. Then the subsequent guess is lower. You reversed either the math or the phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ans = False:
```

should be

```
while ans == False:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Is the number", c , "?")
    d = input("Enter Y if correct / L if your number is lower or H if higher:")
    if d in ["Y" , "y"]:
        ans = True
    elif d in ["H"]:
        high = c
        c = int((c + low) / 2)
        compscore = compscore + 1
    elif d in ["L"]:
        low = c
        c = int((c + high) / 2)
        compscore = compscore + 1
    else:
        print ("invalid input")
```

Here you check if d is H (higher) and you calculate like it is lower `((50 + 0) /2) = 25`
So you need to switch that

Also you forgot one more `=` in `while ans = False:`